# R.java file gone all of a sudden

Tags: android, file

I was working on my project and it was fine until recently all of a sudden it went missing when I tried to run the project.This file is auto generated so why did this happen.
In my error log I am getting this error.

"Warning: Ignoring name conflict in resource file for name menu_settings"

Please help me out here.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You check whether there  is any error in your xml files.

Comment: you are using menu_settings twice for 2 things.

Comment: I took relative layout along with scroll view inside relative layout.When I corrected it to Linear layout R file was generated again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your res folder, check with drawable and .xml files, if u have any error in xml Compiler will not generate R.java file and do this... Project -> Clean

Answer (score 1):

`R.java` is autogenerated at compile time. If any error in the `res` folder occurs it can not be genarated. So check inside it for issue. You can use also the `problems` eclipse perspective

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you have error in the xml files under `res` files, like layouts, string.xml etc.

Answer (score 0):

check your resource file there seems some error.thats why your `R.java` not generating.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the Res folder specially images name and XML files follow naming convention for draw able.